# Tests output in multi-package project is not shown with `stack test`

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, test-suite

I have a multi-package project with test suits in every package. When I run `stack test` command I expect output of every package's tests to be shown, but it's not. Here is what I've got:

```
package1-0.1.0.0: test (suite: package1-test)
package2-0.1.0.0: test (suite: package2-test)
package3-0.1.0.0: build (test)
package1-0.1.0.0: Test suite package1-test passed
package3-0.1.0.0: test (suite: package3-test)
package3-0.1.0.0: Test suite package3-test passed
...
```

What I would like to see is something like this:

```
   test/Test.hs
      Test.Pack1
        Ggurda
          skovoroda:  OK (0.41s)
            OK
          patak: OK (7.59s)
            OK
```

I'm able too see detailed test output if I specify package explicitly (`stack test package1:test:package1-test`), but I don't want to do it by hands for all packages I have.

Is there a command that would help to show detailed output of each test results of every package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `--dump-logs` flag or use [the corresponding option](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#dump-logs) by adding the follow line to your `stack.yaml`:

```
dump-logs: all
```